# Table doesn't exist: SHOW KEYS

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I am getting this error when I run db:migrate

```
Mysql2::Error: Table 'sample_app_development.microposts' doesn't exist: SHOW KEYS FROM 
`microposts
```

This is my migration

```
class CreateMicroposts < ActiveRecord::Migration
      def change
        create_table :microposts do |t|
          t.string :content
          t.integer :user_id

          t.timestamps

          add_index :microposts, [:user_id, :created_at]    

        end
      end
    end
```

I have tried restarting mysql and deleting and recreating the database.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Move your `add_index` out of the `create_table`'s block.